# iTerm - Moving back and forward one word is including dash

Tags: iterm

I am wondering is this a M1 vs Intel issue.

I reset both iTerms (on my two machines) to factory and I have tried both setting up Profile > Keys > Key Mappings and Keys > Key Bindings to Send Escape Sequence b and using the Key Mappings to use Natural Text Editing

Given this line `cd ~/dev/my-long-project` and typing option + left

1. My intel will move to between the dash and project.
2. M1 will move to before the tilde.

Is there any way to get the same result as 1 on my M1 Mac?

Comment: What shells are the two machines using?

Comment: Aw the 2nd one is on zsh and the other on bash. Do you know is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Define fix :) zsh is the new default and Apple does not supply an up to date bash so use zsh. But that does the wrong thing according to your question. zsh manuals are https://zsh.sourceforge.io/

Comment: OK fair enough. I guess it is not broken. No idea what im looking for here haha